# Weekdays for all the months in vue js using moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to display all the weekdays(names) of the months for year 2019 using moment js. I am using vue js. Currently I am getting only the current weekdays. Using this code:

```
weeksInMonth: function () {
            var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('isoWeek');
            var endOfWeek = moment().endOf('isoWeek');

            var days = [];
            var day = startOfWeek;

            while (day <= endOfWeek) {
                days.push(day.toDate());
                day = day.clone().add(1, 'd');
            }

            return days;
        },
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question.. how to display it in Vue?

Comment: yes, please. weekdays (names) for the year 2019 in an array, currently i get only for current week

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var startOfYear = moment().startOf('year');
var endOfYear = moment().endOf('year');
```

instead of startofWeek / endOfWeek to get the days of the whole year